# How to check a string is numeric positive

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point

How to check a string is numeric positive and possibly a comma as decimal separator and two decimal places maximum.

Example

10.25 is true
10.2  is true
10.236 is false theres 3 decimal
10.dee is false

Comment: Can you post examples of what you consider valid and invalid?

Comment: hint: you're probably looking for a regex

Comment: How large can the numbers be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

or you can use this regexp

```
^[0-9]*([,]{1}[0-9]{0,2}){0,1}$
```

if you want both comma and dot as allowed separator then

```
^[0-9]*([\.,]{1}[0-9]{0,2}){0,1}$
```

Answer (score 4):

If a string represents negative number then it must be prefixed with a minus sign, regardless of the precision, number format or decimal separator used:

```
if(string.equals("0.0") || !string.startsWith("-"))  {
    //string is positive
}
```

Comment: **0.0** is not positive and it doens't have the "-"

Comment: Should be `!string.equals("0.0")`

Answer (score 3):

To check for numeric, use:

```
Double number = Double.parseDouble(string);
return number > 0;
```

**UPDATE:

For comma as seperator, you can use the following:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse(string);
double d = number.doubleValue();
return number > 0;
```

Comment: Or `boolean positive = Double.parseDouble(string) > 0`

Comment: what if the format of the string doesn't match the number format for the current `Locale`?

Comment: @ninesided it has nothing to do with a Locale

Comment: @Adel Boutros: !?  OP wrote in his answer that 10.236 should return *false* because the number can only have *"two decimal places maximum"* [sic]...

Comment: @user988052 He has 3 questions, I only answered the first one

Comment: @alf I thought your Locale determined the default number format used when parsing numbers, like the decimal separator to use etc.?

Comment: @ninesided no it's not used by `Double.parseDouble`. It's always a decimal dot, no thousand separators are allowed, etc. Fixed format, check the docs.

Comment: aah, fair enough, so parseDouble with a comma as the decimal seperator, as described in the OP would throw an exception in this case

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:
Convert to a double first. That will test for numeric.
If that fails;
convert the last comma in a period (indexOf, replace).
Then convert again.

For making sure you have 2 decimal places maximum - there's functions for that in DecimalFormat...
But for alternatives, see this question here. [Rounding a double to 5 decimal places in Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451149/rounding-a-double-to-5-decimal-places-in-java-me)

After you have the double converted and stored to 2 decimal places, you can check if it's negative.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the sign of a number is to use [`signum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29) provided by `Math` lib.

```
Math.signum(yourDouble);
```

> Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument is less than zero

Comment: `Math.signum` doesn't take a `String` though?

Comment: true, I was wondering why everyone suggested `string.foo()` until I reread the question -.-

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use BigDecimal:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TestBigDecimal2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = { "10.25", "-10.25", "10.2", "10.236", "10.dee" };
        for(String value : values) {
            System.out.println(value + " is valid: " + checkValid(value));
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkValid(String value) {
        try {
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(value);
            return decimal.signum() > 0 && decimal.scale() < 3;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
that returns true if is a positive integer and false if not.

```
public static boolean isPositiveInteger(String str) {

    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int length = str.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
            return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        boolean isDigit = (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
        if (!isDigit) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```