# convert double value from 1 decimal to 2 decimal places in j2me

Tags: java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounding a double to 5 decimal places in Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451149/rounding-a-double-to-5-decimal-places-in-java-me)

i have a double value which is 2.8. I was planning to display on screen in the form of 2.80. Is there any idea how to do it? 
thanks=)

Comment: The original value is different. What i need is from 1 decimal place (2.8) to 2 decimal places. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DecimalFormat class, in Java SE, can handle this scenario. Unfortunately, Java ME doesn't have it or anything similar to it.
I think the solution is to convert the double value to string and add the extra '0' at the end.

```
String formattedValue = Double.toString(value).concat("0");
```